# How to define parameter behavior in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to define a comma-separated number type matching numbers like `111,111` or `1111,1111` where the position of the comma is flexible. What I am trying to achieve is something like when you do `xsd:string {length="4"}` and the `length` parameter will limit the length of the matching string. So in my case, say my type is called `myNumber` and the parameter name is `groupDigits` so that when I do `xsd:myNumber {groupDigits="3"}` the matching number would be `111,111` and if it's `4` the matching number would be `111,1111`. How can I define this `groupDigits` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [schema regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html) which will match strings with your comma-separated number types.

Typically though, when you write this regular expression, at that point you'll be forced to commit in writing the regex how many numbers you want between individual commas.

Now if I understand the question correctly, you want to define a regular expression that is variable depending on some input that you provide.   I don't think that's possible because there's no mechanism in schema for passing the variable to the regular expression.  There's also no mechanism for referring to an outside variable from within one of those regular expressions.

XML schema matches context free grammars, and by introducing this variable, you'd be making it into a context-sensitive language, so that's not going to work.

If you really, really absolutely have to have this feature, you could consider using XSLT to dynamically generate the schema itself.   The XSLT would be a program which takes your parameter and produces the right regular expression.  Its output would be a one-shot schema which would validate according to the pattern you need in a given context.